# Best ways to protect against CSRF attacks in PHP

Tags: php, security, csrf

What is the best way to protect again `CSRF` attacks in PHP.

It has been recommend to use form tokens, so basically generate a random value and store it in a hidden field. Then also store this random value in the users session.

Finally in the form action, make sure the session and form token match.

```
if($_SESSION['token'] !== $_POST['token']) {
   die("bad... spanking...");
}
```

Is there a better/easier way, as this requires a lot of code modification in my application (lots of forms and actions).

Comment: Using CSRF prevention tokens is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  To protect against CSRF, you need to make sure you only trust credentials that are automatically appended to requests (like cookies) when you have reason to believe that the user actually submitted your form.  The only way to do that is to have the form carry some kind of secret that the server uses to authorize processing.

If you use a framework or library to compose your form it might help by generating the random number, setting the cookie or session property, and adding the hidden input to your form but those three steps do need to happen.

Comment: What about checking `referer`?

Comment: http://www.cgisecurity.com/csrf-faq.html#referer says no: "First there are many ways that a Referer header can be blanked out or modified such as via web filtering software, parental control software, privacy software, proxies, or DOM trickery. This makes the referer header unreliable by nature.
Second Referer headers can be spoofed using XMLHTTP and by using flash as demonstrated by Amit Klein and rapid7. While these particular methods have been patched by the vendors, not every user visiting your website has applied these patches. Even if they did the first issue would still exist."

Comment: Ok, should I generate a new `token` on each page reload? So every reload generates a new token, stores it in session, and set it in the hidden field?

Comment: @Justin, you want a token to be fairly short lived, but if the user has two pages from your site open at the same time, and those two pages share the session, then you might get situations where the user is denied access from one form if you generate a token on every reload.